# Find the range of values of $k$ for which the quadratic equation $9x^2+8x-2k=0$ has 2 distinct real roots.

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

How do I do I do this question?
I've wrote down $b^2-4ac>0$ because it has 2 distinct real roots. And put the numbers into that equation $8^2-4(9)(-2k)$ and got $64+72k=0$.
What do I need to do next please to work out the values of $k$ (answer the question)?

Comment: You should have $64 + 72 k > 0$. This gives you the range of $k$ you want.

Comment: Sorry. How do I get the value of K though from that?

Comment: Reduce this above inequality into the form $k > \dots$.

Comment: Ok thank you :)

Comment: "I've wrote down $b^2−4ac>0$ because ...." and then you write "and got$ 64+72k=0$".  .... Shouldn't you have gotten $64 +72k > 0$?... which gives you $72k > -64$ and .....

Comment: I accidentally put =0 instead of >0

Comment: But you know how to solve $64 +72k > 0$?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions to $9x^2 +8x-2k = 0$ will have solutions $x = \frac {-8 +\sqrt {8^2 -4\times 9\times (-2k)}}{2\times 9}$ and $x = \frac {-8 -\sqrt {8^2 -4\times 9\times (-2k)}}{2\times 9}$

Sometimes those two answers will be two distinct answers, sometimes those answers will only be one single answer, sometimes those answers will never exist and all.

so the question is:  What must be true about $k$ for those to be two different answers and not both the same or not existing at all.

.... take a few minutes to think that out.... don't read ahead until you think it through....

....... don't read ........

....... don't read .......

...... don't read........

Okay, those answers will but distinct when $-\sqrt{8^2 - 4\times 9\times (-2k)} \ne +\sqrt{8^2 -4\times 9\times (-2k)}$.  Those answer will be the same answer if $-\sqrt{8^2 - 4\times 9\times (-2k)} = +\sqrt{8^2 -4\times 9\times (-2k)}$.  And those answers wont exist if $-\sqrt{8^2 - 4\times 9\times (-2k)}$ or $ +\sqrt{8^2 -4\times 9\times (-2k)}$ don't exist.

So when do those happen?

...... don't read.......

....... don't read.......

....... don't read......

Okay, those answers will not exist and all  of $\sqrt {8^2 -4\times 9 \times (-2k)}$ is the square root of a negative number.  They will be equal if $-\sqrt{8^2 - 4\times 9\times (-2k)} = +\sqrt{8^2 -4\times 9\times (-2k)}$ which will happen if $\pm \sqrt{8^2 - 4\times 9\times (-2k)} = 0$.  And they'll be different values if it is the square root of a positive numbers.

So:  There will be two distinct solutions if $8^2 -4\times 9 \times (-2k)$ is positive.

There will be one double root if $8^2 -4\times 9 \times (-2k)=0$.

And there will be no solutions if $8^2 -4\times 9 \times (-2k)$ is negative.

So you need to solve:  $8^2 -4\times 9 \times (-2k) > 0$

> $64 + 72k > 0$

> $72k > -64$

> $k > -\frac {64}{72}=-\frac 89$.

> If $k > -\frac 89$ then there are two distinct solutions.  If $k = -\frac 89$ there is one double root.  If $k< - \frac 89$ there are no real solutions (and two complex solutions).

> If $k > -\frac 89$ then that two solutions are $x=\frac {-8\pm\sqrt{64+72k}}{18}= \frac {-8\pm 2\sqrt{16+18k}}{18}=\frac {-4\pm\sqrt{2(8+9k)}}9$.  If $k = -\frac 89$ then the two solutions are $x =x=\frac {-8\pm\sqrt{64+72(-\frac 89)}}{18} = \frac {-8\pm\sqrt{64-8\times 8}}{18}=\frac {-8\pm 0}{18}=-\frac 49$.  And if $k > \frac 89$ then $x=\frac {-8\pm\sqrt{64+72k}}{18}=\frac {-8\pm\sqrt{(-1)(72|k| -64)}}{18}= \frac {-8\pm 2\sqrt{18|k|-16}i}{18}=\frac {-4\pm \sqrt{2(9|k|-8)}i}2$; two *non* real roots (where $i$ is the purely imaginary number so that $i^2 = -1$.)

Comment: +1 for (among other things) the *offbeat* nature of your presentation

Comment: Actually I fell a little bad as had I read the question more carefully I'd have realized the OP understood everything up to figuring out that $64+72k > 0$ and only had trouble solving that which I took to be routine and not requiring explanation.